# To show $X$ and $|X|$ are not jointly continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Suppose $X\in N(0,1)$. Show that $X$ and $|X|$ are not jointly continuous.

I am not sure how I can approach this problem. But the following method seems plausible to me:

> $$P(X\leq x||X|=u)=\lim_{a\to0}\dfrac{P(X\leq x,|X|\in (u-a,u+a))}{P(|X|\in (u-a,u+a))}$$

Of course we must have $u>0$. Now let $-u<x<u$ then after some stage, I will get $a$ so small that $x$ will not belong to $(u-a,u+a)$ or $(-u-a,-u+a)$. In that case, the intersection of $(-\infty,x)$ and $(-u-a,-u+a)\cup(-u-a,-u+a)$ will be $(-u-a,-u+a)$ due to which the result becomes:

> $$\lim_{a\to0}\dfrac{P(X\in(-u-a,-u+a))}{P(X\in(-u-a,-u+a))+P(X\in(u-a,u+a))}=\lim_{a\to0}\dfrac{\Phi(-u+a)-\Phi(-u-a)}{\Phi(-u+a)-\Phi(-u-a)+\Phi(u+a)-\Phi(u-a)}=0.5$$

Now for $x<-u$, the intersection $\{X\leq x\}$ with $\{|X|\in(u-a,u+a)\}$ is null, hence the numerator is $0$, so the probability is $0$. If $x>u$ then the probability is $1$.

Hence $P(X\leq x||X|=u)=0$ if $x<-u$, is $0.5$ if $-u<x<u$ and is $1$ if $x>u$. So it has two jumps and cannot be a continuous distribution function, and hence cannot have a density. But this density is precisely the conditional density of $X$ on $|X|$, which therefore does not exist. This can happen only when $f_{X,|X|}(x,u)$ does not exist, which shows there is no joint density of $X$ and $|X|$.

Comment: What is your _definition_ of joint continuity of two random variables?

Comment: If the joint density exists, then I think $X$ and $Y$ are said to be jointly continuous. That is, if the joint distribution function is differentiable. However, in this case, working with the joint distribution may turn out to be hard. Hence I resorted to this alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Just for ease of notation, let $Y=|X|$. If $X,Y$ are jointly continuous then integrating over all possible values for $X,Y$, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 &=& \int_{x=-\infty}^{0}\int_{y=-x}^{-x}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dx\;dy}
+ \int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=x}^{x}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)\;dx\;dy} \\
 && \\
&=& 0+0 \qquad\qquad\text{both inner integrals are $0$ due to their limits of integration.}
\end{eqnarray*}

This is a contradiction, so $X,Y$ are not jointly continuous.